search() got an unexpected keyword argument 'query'
I want to implement the search function with the Django Web framework. I'm working on fetching public data (API) and fetching the data corresponding to the search results and showing it on the index.html page.
Is it search view!
def search(request):
    base_url = "http://apis.data.go.kr/5710000/benlService/nltyArtList"
    image_api_url = "http://apis.data.go.kr/5710000/benlService/artImgList"

    # 검색어 가져오기
    search_query = request.GET.get('q', '')

    params = {                            "serviceKey":"gKat/nvnmi8i9zoiX+JsGzCTsAV75gkvU71APhj8FbnH3yX4kiZMuseZunM0ZpcvKZaMD0XsmeBHW8dVj8HQxg==",
        "pageNo": "1",
        "numOfRows": "5",
        "returnType": "json",
        "artNm": search_query
    }

    response = requests.get(base_url, params=params)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        art_list = data['response']['body']['items']['item']

        # 작품 이미지 정보
        for art in art_list:
            image_params = {
       "serviceKey":"gKat/nvnmi8i9zoiX+JsGzCTsAV75gkvU71APhj8FbnH3yX4kiZMuseZunM0ZpcvKZaMD0XsmeBHW8dVj8HQxg==",
                "pageNo": "1",
                "numOfRows": "5",
                "returnType": "json",
                "artNm": art["artNm"]  # 'art_name' 대신 'art["artNm"]' 사용
            }

            image_response = requests.get(image_api_url, params=image_params)
            if image_response.status_code == 200:
                image_data = image_response.json()
                if 'item' in image_data['response']['body']['items']:
                    art["image_url"] = image_data["response"]["body"]["items"]["item"]["imgUrl"]
                else:
                    art["image_url"] = None
            else:
                art["image_url"] = None
    else:
        # 에러 처리
        print("API 요청 실패:", response.status_code)
        art_list = []

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'art_list': art_list, 'search_query': search_query})

Is it urls.py path setting:
urlpatterns = [# path('', views.index, name='index'),  # 예를 들어, index view로 연결path('', views.openapi_view, name='index'),path('search/<str:query>/', views.search, name='search'),]


Be careful when accessing data like that. You might raise a KeyError exception.

@VLAZ web tag should rightly be removed yes? But search tag is not quite right is it? I think you will see what I’m talking about.

@ChukwujiobiCanon you could have just edited it yourself. I'm not paying attention to every single tag on a question because I'm going over a dozen or more questions at a time. I reckoned that if somebody finds a tag that doesn't belong they could change it.

views.search() will be caled this way by Django when a HttpRequest arrives for the URL path 'search':
views.search(request, "some-query")
The internals is a bit more complex but that is essentially it. That path is expected to be invoked by a HTTP client as follows: "http[s]://DOMAIN/search/some-query/".
Since it is a dynamic URL, write the function signature in such a way that it can receive the dynamic URL value when Django invokes the view with the value.
def search(request, query: str):
    #•••Rest of code•••
The type hint is not required.

Thank you!! I will try it later and leave a comment!!

def search(request, query: str):
str = request.GET.get('q', '')
print(f"how{str}")
how about that?

You’ve got the function signature right now. Also do not name a variable str. That is an inbuilt class name. Do you send any HTTP GET method parameters like: "http[s]://DOMAIN/search/some-query?q=some-parameter"? I thought you used query and that it because that was what you wanted. Something like: print(f"how {query}"). Never mind, I have OCD so it just bothered me a little that you now use two media to communicate dynamic values to the server during a GET request. By the way nothing stops you from doing that.

If you need more information, take a look at URL path resolution and URL QueryDict separately.

If this solves your question, mark as your accepted answer.

i did it accepted your answer
